# Caching responses in DRF

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, etag

I have a REST API and some of the endpoints take a significant time to generate the responses, so I want to add some response caching and etag support. I have looked at the conditional response implementation in Django and at both response caching and conditional response in DRF extensions package. The problem I am having is that my data changes very frequently on one side, but is also heavily segregated, so if something changes in the response to user A calling endpoint X, nothing might change for users B, C and D calling the same endpoint. Since my data changes often, if I invalidate all responses on every change, I will never hit cache. The endpoints in question all generate lists of JSON objects, so the question is how can I only invalidate cached responses that contain a changed object rather than invalidating all of them?